# MYSQL Recursive query with conditions

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables,
the first table contains id_product, its rate and its price.

| ID_product | rate | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TSA1 | 0.12 |
| 2 | TSA1 | 1.5 |
| 1 | TSA2 | 0.14 |
| 2 | TSA2 | 1.7 |
| 1 | TSA3 | NULL |
| 2 | TSA3 | 1.7 |
| 1 | TASM4 | 1.68 |

I have an other table which contains a rate and its rate destination if the price for its rate is NULL. Its for always has a price for each product. Here for example, the product 1 doesnt have a price for the rate TSA3. The correspondance table says that if it doesnt have a price for this rate, use the price of TASM4.

| Origin_rate | Destination_rate |
| --- | --- |
| TSA1 | TAS2 |
| TSA2 | TAS3 |
| TSA3 | TASM4 |

So, How can I complete my first table? I think, i need a recursive query, but i dont know how to do it in SQL.

Comment: You think of a recursive query because the row can have a rate the price of which is null, then you look up the substitute rate, but that too can have a price of null, so you must again look for a substitute rate?

Comment: exactly , rate are like a linked list, at the end it has necessary a price

Comment: a) which MySQL version do you use b) what do you mean "complete first table"? do you want to update the missing rate, or be able (in a query) to get the correct rate for null values?

Comment: Why are there `ID_product` duplicates in your first table, is this intentional? Also, just to double-check, when the price is `NULL` and the rate is `TSA1`, then it still is supposed to become `TSAM4` in the end?

Comment: The price of each product depends of its rate, so i have all products duplicated for each rate. Sometimes a product doesnt have a price with a rate, so the other table indicate which rate use if this rate doesnt have a price. Sometimes its after 5 rates that a product has a price. I want complete all null price in my first table.

Comment: Show desired output for shown source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query gets you the price hirarchically:

```
with recursive cte(id_product, rate, price, origin_rate) as
(
  select id_product, rate, price, rate
  from mytable
  union all
  select cte.id_product, cte.rate, t.price, t.rate
  from cte
  join map on map.origin_rate = cte.origin_rate
  left join mytable t on t.id_product = cte.id_product
                     and t.rate = map.destination_rate
  where cte.price is null
)
select id_product, rate, price
from cte
where price is not null
order by id_product, rate;
```