# How to retrieve all the children recursively with sequelize-typescript using NestJS

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js, nest, sequelize-typescript

I wanted to seek with sequelize-typescript using NestJS.

Problem: I am trying to retrieve all the **children recursively**, like category table has sub category, sub sub category to an infinite level using parent id.

What I have done so far, is trying to add **include** in default scopes but in that case it gets **Maximum call stack size exceeded**, and in case if I add a scope with nested: true, it fetches for 2 levels only.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend to use a plain SQL recursive query if your DBMS supports it

Comment: @Anatoly, thanks for the reply, can you suggest any examples ?

Comment: You need to indicate what DBMS you have. For instance, I can show an example for PostgreSQL

Comment: I am working with MySQL or Sqlite, so if you can share anything relevant, it will be super helpful.

Comment: For MySQL you can look at the example of recursive query here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70774160/1376618

Comment: For SQLite see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html p.3.1